# Silverlight 4.0 - Memory crash with 20.000 data to display

Tags: silverlight, memory, gantt-chart

I've a radiantQ gantt control and 20.000 data recived from wcf service to display. When less data to display it works like a charm. But i need to diplay 20.000 records and all browsers crash-freeze. Is there any way to solve this problem? Increasing isolated-storage may works?

thanks.

Comment: what data is it? How much memory does it consume?

Comment: Increasing isolated storage isn't going to help unless you use it to cache your data locally.

Comment: @EmilVikström how can i see how much memory it consume?

Comment: @ChrisF thanks. i thought silverlight may use isolated-storage for memory too.

Answer (score 1):

@halil ibrahim,

Please contact RadiantQ Technical Support and we will provide you hints on how to optimize gantt usage with large amounts of data.

Answer (score 1):

Does application crash in rendering mode (when you display data on UI)? - You can use virtualization mode. You can try create one more thread (task or use background worker) and display parts of data to UI in "stack" mode. Do not load all data on first step. It should work. I tried do it: load of 1000+ data items from service and display it on UI.

Does application crash in process of receiving data from service (when you call a service method)? - You should configure your service. Increase max receive message size, etc. It depend on service, which you use.

Comment: Thanks Vitaliy, that solved a part of the problem. Now it's able to load data without any crash.But after step by step loading, still the data is huge and rendering continues to be a problem. Any suggestion?

Comment: You can load not all data, but only these, which user can see. For example: You have a form, which can display 50 items. You can bind 100 items and add more, when user will scroll down.